# Other pages fine but wp-admin showing ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS Error

Tags: redirect, htaccess, errors, wp-redirect, wp-config

wp-admin showing ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS Error and can't let me login into dashboard but Other pages loading fine. **FIXED**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE :
FIXED**

okay guys I have solved this issue here is my fix

1- first of all you will need access to FTP or C-panel
2- go to public_html > now for this to work plz reset your wp-config.php you can do it by removing unnecessary code,  here is a sample wp-config.php (if you don't have) :

```
<?php
/**
 * The base configuration for WordPress
 *
 * The wp-config.php creation script uses this file during the installation.
 * You don't have to use the web site, you can copy this file to "wp-config.php"
 * and fill in the values.
 *
 * This file contains the following configurations:
 *
 * * Database settings
 * * Secret keys
 * * Database table prefix
 * * ABSPATH
 *
 * @link https://wordpress.org/support/article/editing-wp-config-php/
 *
 * @package WordPress
 */

// ** Database settings - You can get this info from your web host ** //
/** The name of the database for WordPress */
define( 'DB_NAME', 'database_name_here' );

/** Database username */
define( 'DB_USER', 'username_here' );

/** Database password */
define( 'DB_PASSWORD', 'password_here' );

/** Database hostname */
define( 'DB_HOST', 'localhost' );

/** Database charset to use in creating database tables. */
define( 'DB_CHARSET', 'utf8' );

/** The database collate type. Don't change this if in doubt. */
define( 'DB_COLLATE', '' );

/**#@+
 * Authentication unique keys and salts.
 *
 * Change these to different unique phrases! You can generate these using
 * the {@link https://api.wordpress.org/secret-key/1.1/salt/ WordPress.org secret-key service}.
 *
 * You can change these at any point in time to invalidate all existing cookies.
 * This will force all users to have to log in again.
 *
 * @since 2.6.0
 */
define( 'AUTH_KEY',         'put your unique phrase here' );
define( 'SECURE_AUTH_KEY',  'put your unique phrase here' );
define( 'LOGGED_IN_KEY',    'put your unique phrase here' );
define( 'NONCE_KEY',        'put your unique phrase here' );
define( 'AUTH_SALT',        'put your unique phrase here' );
define( 'SECURE_AUTH_SALT', 'put your unique phrase here' );
define( 'LOGGED_IN_SALT',   'put your unique phrase here' );
define( 'NONCE_SALT',       'put your unique phrase here' );

/**#@-*/

/**
 * WordPress database table prefix.
 *
 * You can have multiple installations in one database if you give each
 * a unique prefix. Only numbers, letters, and underscores please!
 */
$table_prefix = 'wp_';

/**
 * For developers: WordPress debugging mode.
 *
 * Change this to true to enable the display of notices during development.
 * It is strongly recommended that plugin and theme developers use WP_DEBUG
 * in their development environments.
 *
 * For information on other constants that can be used for debugging,
 * visit the documentation.
 *
 * @link https://wordpress.org/support/article/debugging-in-wordpress/
 */
define( 'WP_DEBUG', false );

/* Add any custom values between this line and the "stop editing" line. */



/* That's all, stop editing! Happy publishing. */

/** Absolute path to the WordPress directory. */
if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    define( 'ABSPATH', __DIR__ . '/' );
}

/** Sets up WordPress vars and included files. */
require_once ABSPATH . 'wp-settings.php';
```

**Now remember to change define value by your wp-config.php values ,
Inshort Remove previous answer solutions that requires changes in wp-config.php**

now visit your your site admin area and when it starts loading quickly delete .htaccesss file from  public_html or from root directory it will load you to the login page

I repeat: when wp-admin starts to load quickly delete .htaccess file

- **Now this is a temporary fix  follow these steps for complete fix**

if renaming plugins, themes didn't helped, download or backup your **wp-config.php** from the root directory , In the root directory delete all the files and  folders **except wp-content** folder

- Download a fresh copy of wordpress from wordpress.org and paste all the fresh files in your root directory **remember don't paste the wp-content folder**

install wordpress enter the database credentials from the wp-config file I said to download earlier

NOTE: I reset the wordpress database via php admin if you have phpmyadmin access do it from there otherwise try to **dowload reset wordpress plugin** from the temporary fix If you don't have access to phpmyadmin and dashboard

THIS WILL AND SHOULD SOLVE YOUR PROBLEM_ Thanks

regards: Rawaha